# Designing query to select count from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, computer-science

[This is the schema for my questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdPiM.png)

Hi, I don't have experience in SQL Developer and I'm trying to build a query for the following question:

I need that for each DVD in the catalog, display the title, length, release_date, and how many times it has been checked out by all customers across all libraries. 
Also I want to include those that have not been checked out yet displaying 0, and sort results by title.

So far I have this in the query but I'm stock here:

```
--Question C. ************* VERIFY
Select
    Catalog_Item.Title,
    DVD.Length,
    Catalog_Item.Release_Date,
    (
        Select 
            Count(Transaction.Transaction_ID) 
        From Transaction 
        Where
            DVD.Catalog_Item_ID = Physical_Item.Catalog_Item_ID
            And Physical_Item.Physical_Item_ID = Transaction.Physical_Item_ID
    ) as "Total_DVD"
From 
    Catalog_Item,DVD,
    Physical_Item
Group by
    Catalog_Item.Title,
    DVD.Length,
    Catalog_Item.Release_Date
```

If I run this exact query I get error

```
Not a Group By Expression
```

And if I exclude the GROUP BY, I get results by doesn't look like the correct outputs.

Any suggestions on what syntax I can use to achieve the desired output? Thanks!

Comment: your problem is the join... you don't have the joint field... problem with using ancient method for inner join.

Comment: I tried using the inner join for each table out side the sub-query but still getting pretty much the same output or error.

Answer (score 1):

You put three tables to the query but you missed to link them. If you don't link them, you will see too much-duplicated rows.
Also, your sub-query links were wrong, I assume you tried to put the links here that you missed in the main query.

I believe you need something like that:

```
Select
     CI.Title
    ,DVD.Length
    ,CI.Release_Date
    ,NVL(TR.TotalTransactions,0) TotalTransactions
From  Catalog_Item CI
INNER JOIN DVD ON DVD.Catalog_Item_ID  = CI.Catalog_Item_ID 
LEFT JOIN Physical_Item PHI  ON CI.Catalog_Item_ID = PHI.Catalog_Item_ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Physical_Item_ID
                , Count(Transaction_ID) TotalTransactions
            FROM Transaction 
            GROUP BY Physical_Item_ID
            ) TR ON PHI.Physical_Item_ID = TR.Physical_Item_ID
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I did tried linking the 3 tables using the inner join but I still get the exact same output or errors. I tried using your suggestion and change the `ISNULL`  for `NVL` (I'm using Oracle SQL Dev) and now I'm getting a closer output to what I want. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: You are right, I missed the database you provided. I will update the query.

Comment: Other question. If instead of showing `0` at the output for `NULL`, I want to not show at all `NULL` values, how is the correct way to accommodate the syntax?

Comment: @CrsCrz simply change the LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

For a start, join Catalog_Item, Physical_Item and DVD together. Without appropriate join conditions, these three tables will join using a cartesian product join - which is probably one of the reasons why you are seeing unexpected results.